# How do you measure maximum dimensions?

Tags: catia

Let's say I want to measure the minimum package for a part, calculating the maximum length, height and width (see image in Measure Intertia Tool, you'll find a green, red and blue line representing what i want to measure)

This tool gives you the most complex measurments but not the lines it is capable of drawing. Maybe with macros? I'm not such an expert.

Link:

http://catiadoc.free.fr/online/cfyugmeasure_C2/cfyugmeasureinertia01.htm

Comment: Solved: Found this, it's called bounding box: https://www.cadcam-group.eu/catia-v5-bounding-box

Comment: Be aware that this is not giving always the smallest Bounding Box, is all depending how the part was created. The best solution is with a macro where you can pick some elements. There are several macros on web, you can try to find them on CATIA forums.

Comment: The minimum package box (what you are looking for) is not directly related to the inertial axis (which the CATIA bounding box is based on). The only way to find it is an optimization algorithm (there's no mathematical formula)